# how to exclude line numbers for an empty line

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to implement an extra feature in Tkinter recently. My question is pretty easy to understand. Below I have mentioned my code and XML file.

Data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<p1:FILE xmlns:p1="http://www.example.org/eHorizon">


     <Time nTimestamp="12">
            <Test>
                <Car/>
            </Test>
     </Time>
</p1:FILE>
```

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from distutils.filelist import findall
from lxml import etree

fileOpen = open("C:/Users/your-location/data.xml")

root = Tk()
text = Text(root, height=30, width = 40)
text.pack()

text.insert(END,fileOpen.read())

recovering_parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
xmlLog = etree.parse("C:/Users/your-location/data.xml",parser=recovering_parser).getroot()    

ElementsList = xmlLog.findall("Time")

print "The line number of Time element is = ", ElementsList[0].sourceline #prints 5, 
                       #but I want to ignore blank lines and print #answer as 3 (please look in notepad++ format below)

root.mainloop()
```

data.xml in notepad++:

[image]

**What I want:**

I just want to omit line numbers wherever there are empty lines. So whenever I make use of `sourceline` it should return line number excluding all the spaces

In above code `print "The line number of Time element is = ", ElementsList[0].sourceline` should print answer 3(not including blank lines) and not 5(including blank lines).

**What I tried:**

I tried searching everywhere but didn't got what I wanted. Frankly, as of now I am not able to think even how to initiate. I am already making use of `sourceline` which is simply returning given line numbers considering all spaces.

**EDIT:** I am making use of `sourceline` because I am dealing with xml elements and using lxml library to extract xml data.

Comment: I'm not sure where `sourceline` comes from, but what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @Jkdc I added EDIT in question. `sourceline` is used to extract line numbers as the lxml library parses xml document. Expected output is when I extract line number of above given data in textbox, `1` should belong to `line 1` and `2` to `line 2`. In above case it 2 belongs to `line 3`.

Comment: "My question is pretty easy to understand." Actually I'm having a hard time understanding what you are doing. Why don't you share code (as you should almost every time on stackoverflow) that shows how to produce that tkinter window, then how you are getting your incorrect data, and finally show the exact data that you expect to get? In other words, a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @KobeJohn Thank you for response. I edited entire question. Previously I thought of keeping question more short and to the point. but details were not enough.

Comment: I posted a direct answer but... why? Why would you want to remove blank lines? How is that number useful? I feel like there must be a better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @KobeJohn I am working on xml comparison. so lets say if there are `3` points in `A file` and `2` files in `B file`. I would simply drop a new blank line in `B file` by correctly extracting the line number of where blank has to be introduced. Now for instance if there is a big file and if you drop blanks anywhere,then all the info of line numbers that i gathered for those points will get altered since blank lines will also have their own line number. But if we can exclude those gaps from taking line numbers then our order of missing points will have same line number as it was when parsed

Comment: The plan to drop blanks or new line is to keep order of files in proper alignment when displayed in text box of tkinter.

Comment: I see! Thanks for explaining. As an alternative, you could add meta-data to the xml file to show what the original line was. I did something similar in the previous tkinter + xml QA we worked on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. but in my project these xml files are generating automatically and I've been told that you cannot edit them. They have to be preserved as it is. But tomorrow I will see again regarding what can I do with meta data as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it this way, there are two options I see:

## Remove blank lines

Recreate the file without the blank lines.

## Track blank lines

Track how many blank lines exist up to each actual source line number. Subtract that from the actual source line number.

```
# track blanks
blanks_before_line = [0]
with open('data.xml') as f:
    for line in f:
        new_blanks = blanks_before_line[-1]
        if not line.strip():
            new_blanks += 1
        blanks_before_line.append(new_blanks)

# now in your code subtract it
# .....
real_sourceline = ElementsList[0].sourceline
adjusted_sourceline = real_sourceline - blanks_before_line[real_sourceline - 1]
print "The line number of Time element is = ", adjusted_sourceline
```